# How to get the ASP.net objects to appear on the same line?

Tags: asp.net, image, linkbutton

I'm sure this has been asked before but I'm not finding an answer...We have a clickable header column followed by an invisible image for sorting purposes. When a user clicks on the link the sorting takes place on the desired column as expected but the ascending / descending gifs appear below the column header text not to the side. How can we force it to appear to the side of column text?

...

```
<th style="vertical-align:middle; padding-left:2em; padding-right:2em; border:1px solid black;">
      <asp:LinkButton style="font-size:larger" ID="lnkGenre" CommandName="Sort"  CommandArgument="Genre" runat="server">Genre</asp:LinkButton>
      <asp:Image runat="server" ID="SortImage4" ImageUrl="Resources/ascending.gif" Visible="false" />
</th>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have inline styles already, add `white-space:nowrap` to the styles on your `<th>`